# Simple explanation of CKKS scheme

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I'm searching for a (preferably simple) explanation of the Cheon-Kim-Kim-Song scheme for fully homomorphic encryption.

All I did find so far is the original paper, which is rather difficult to understand for me. (Link: https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/421.pdf)

Anything is appreciated (text, videos, powerpoints etc.). Thanks for your help.

Comment: For a good explanation it is very important to show which part you don't understand. I had a friend at university that complained about the amount of text while I was complaining about the amount of formulas...

Comment: To be honest, there's much I don't understand. I'm not an expert in cryptography, but have some basic knowledge. I use Microsofts SEAL library, and want to understand it. I found a very good article explaining the BFV scheme (https://blog.n1analytics.com/homomorphic-encryption-illustrated-primer/), and thought maybe there exists something similar for CKKS. 
In general, I'd be interested in a (layman) explanation of Table 1 (on page 10).